# multivariate distribution will additional correlation structure

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis

I am wanting to generate a dataset of $N = 1,000,000$ simulated examinees according to the following constraints:

1. All 1e6 take a battery of 10 subtests
2. All 10 of the subtests have a population mean of 100 and a
   population standard deviation of 15
3. All of the subtests have a correlation matrix of $\mathbf S$
4. The within-person scatter from one subtest to another follows a
   normal distribution with mean = $M$ and standard deviation $\sigma$

In R, there are commands that will sample multivariate distributions that obey a particular correlation matrix.  But is there any command or library that will sample multivariate distributions according to the parameters I have listed above?